# Hard Reset/Data Wipe Android Device through android application

Tags: android, reset, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

I am developing an Android Application to wipe all data from Android including photos, videos, contacts, messages, apps,call logs, application data etc. programmatically. I wish to achieve this with an Android Application only and not through adb.

The approach I am thinking of somehow I manage to Clear data from phone and rewrite the memory with some junk files or binary data 1010 say. (Its just an idea!)

All I have managed to do is delete photos,videos,images,contacts,call logs,messages from Device using **Cursor** and **getContentResolver**. But we can recover that using third party Data Recover Softwares.

I have also reset the device using **device administrator** but the cons of this is the data can be recovered through it.

So, all i need is which approach to follow for hard resetting the device.

I have used below code .

```
 public static void deleteAllContacts(Context activity) {
        ContentResolver contentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String lookupKey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_LOOKUP_URI, lookupKey);
            contentResolver.delete(uri, null, null);
        }
    }

    public static void deleteAllCallLog(Context activity) {
        activity.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
    }

 /*   public static void deleteAllMessages(Context activity) {
        ContentResolver localContentResolver = activity.getContentResolver();
        Uri localUri = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        for (int i = localContentResolver.delete(Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI, null, null); i == 1; i = localContentResolver.delete(localUri, null, null)) {

        }

    }*/


    public static void deleteVideoFiles(Activity activity) {
        String[] videoProjection = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE};
        Cursor videoCursor = activity.managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, videoProjection, null, null, null);
        int count = videoCursor.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int indexID = videoCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
            videoCursor.moveToPosition(i);
            String path = getVideoFilePath(videoCursor.getString(indexID), activity);
            Log.d("Video Path", path);
            File file = new File(path);
            boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
            Log.d("isDELETED", String.valueOf(isDeleted));
        }
        videoCursor.close();
    }

    public static void deleteAudioFiles(Activity activity) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE};
        Cursor audioCursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, null, null, null);
        if (audioCursor != null) {
            if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int indexId = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
                    String path = getAudioFilePath(audioCursor.getString(indexId), activity);
                    Log.d("Audio Path", path);
                    File file = new File(path);
                    boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
                    Log.d("isDELETED", String.valueOf(isDeleted));
                } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
        if (audioCursor != null) audioCursor.close();

    }


    public static void deleteImageFiles(Activity activity) {

        Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA};
        Cursor c = null;
        SortedSet<String> dirList = new TreeSet<String>();
        String[] directories = null;
        if (u != null) {
            c = activity.managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);
        }

        if ((c != null) && (c.moveToFirst())) {
            do {
                String tempDir = c.getString(0);
                tempDir = tempDir.substring(0, tempDir.lastIndexOf("/"));
                try {
                    dirList.add(tempDir);
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
            while (c.moveToNext());
            directories = new String[dirList.size()];
            dirList.toArray(directories);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dirList.size(); i++) {
            File imageDir = new File(directories[i]);
            File[] imageList = imageDir.listFiles();
            if (imageList == null)
                continue;
            for (File imagePath : imageList) {
                try {

                    if (imagePath.isDirectory()) {
                        imageList = imagePath.listFiles();

                    }
                    if (imagePath.getName().contains(".jpg") || imagePath.getName().contains(".JPG")
                            || imagePath.getName().contains(".jpeg") || imagePath.getName().contains(".JPEG")
                            || imagePath.getName().contains(".png") || imagePath.getName().contains(".PNG")
                            || imagePath.getName().contains(".gif") || imagePath.getName().contains(".GIF")
                            || imagePath.getName().contains(".bmp") || imagePath.getName().contains(".BMP")
                            ) {
                        Log.d("Absolute Path", imagePath.getAbsolutePath());
                        File file = new File(imagePath.getAbsolutePath());
                        boolean isDeleted = file.delete();
                        Log.d("iSDELETED", String.valueOf(isDeleted));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }


    }

    public static String getAudioFilePath(String contentId, Activity activity) {
        Uri theMediaUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentId);
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};
        Cursor mCur = activity.getContentResolver().query(theMediaUri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        mCur.moveToFirst();
        return mCur.getString(column_index);

    }


    public static String getVideoFilePath(String contentId, Activity activity) {
        Uri theMediaUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentId);
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
        Cursor mCur = activity.getContentResolver().query(theMediaUri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = mCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
        mCur.moveToFirst();
        return mCur.getString(column_index);
    }

    public static void deleteSMS(Context context) {
      /*  try {
            Uri uriSms = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id", "body"}, null, null, null);

            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    long id = c.getLong(0);
                    Log.d("Body : ", c.getString(1));
                    context.getContentResolver().delete(
                            Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
                    Log.e("Message:", "Message is Deleted successfully");
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }

            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception", e.toString());
        }*/


        Cursor c =context.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), new String[]{"_id", "body"}, null, null,null);
        try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                int id = c.getInt(0);
          int isDeleted =  context.getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);

          Log.d("IS DELETED" , String.valueOf(isDeleted));
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Delete Sms","Error deleting sms",e);
        }finally {
            c.close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have been trying to do so far?

Comment: @DimaKozhevin please see new added description . I have added the code .

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution? I have the same task and I can't seem to find any useful information/